# Converting a wav file to an image and back again

Tags: python

How would i convert a wave file to an image in such a way that i can recover the original wave file from the image, in python please.

I have heard of wav2vec library but its not clear from the documentation how i would convert the vector back into a wave.

```
   ggg=[]
   for wav in os.listdir('/content/drive/My Drive/New folder'):
      fs, data = wavfile.read(wav)
      ggg.append(data)`
```

I would like to append instead the image as i am creating a data-set to train an algorithm on. After completing training, the algorithm will generate images from the same distribution that another piece of code should convert to a wave file.

Comment: Knowing that the wave in a function, with only one value per "column", converting it to an image sounds to me like a really dumb idea, and a very costly way to train the an algorithm, with tons on extra unneeded and meaning less data. But maybe your goal is to only waste CPU cycles!? I would understand a bit more processing the image of an FFT of the waves... If even that!

Comment: Using the raw wave file as the basis of an image by reshaping it thus would work, but that does not take advantage of the fact that a pixel channel can have 255 different values. i thought we could leverage that other wise we need a 15000p image.

Comment: You sure could build a single line of pixels of the 256 gray levels (instead of a 2D black and white image), but still, why not just processing the list of values directly? Most of the machine learning algorithms I've seen can do that...

Comment: it would have to be a deconvolutional network that i am using to map my data to the wave file, but isn't mapping to a whole wave file a bit much in terms of network size? This is a feed forward network